# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'resume'

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, ejs, deployd

Hi im trying to use deployd-template 
https://bitbucket.org/leozero/dpd-template/

I have set all up as it says and also install'ed  ejs

but when i run dpd.template.post....   i get this console error and deployd crash

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\node_modules\doh\lib\handler
.js:42
      req.resume(); // fixes pause causing requests to timeout
          ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'resume'
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\node_modules\doh\lib\
handler.js:42:11
    at Handler.respond (C:\Program Files (x86)\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\node
_modules\doh\lib\respond.js:61:15)
    at Domain.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\n
ode_modules\doh\lib\handler.js:37:13)
    at Domain.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at process._fatalException (node.js:255:29)
```

If i run a template file without ejs code eg.

```
<%= data %>
```

it out puts the template, but as soon as i add ejs code to templete it craches

Comment: Can you try `require('deployd')` from the `node` CLI? Does it throw you any exception?